# Cracks in Garage Floor Causes Cracks in Polyaspartic Garage Floor Coating

Tags: flooring, garage

I recently applied a Polyaspartic coating on our garage floor. There are small but prevalent cracks in this coating, that appears to be caused by the small cracks in the concrete of the garage floor.

We did not seal our garage floor before applying the coating, as it was a new house (*only 1-month-old*). Each crack is about 1/16 of an inch.

I know I could use another lay, but since the multi-color chips have been put down, I am wondering if this second layer will peel.

Any solution will be appreciated.

[Product Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJ17JVD)

Below are some images:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Comment: So you applied this and it soaked into the existing cracks? Apply another coat. You applied it and the concrete and coating cracked? Problem with the concrete...

Comment: i applied this and it soaked into the existing cracks. My only worry, is that they sprinkled the chips (black, blue and white), so will the second layer will peel back?

Comment: > 14. Can I recoat EpoxyShield? How do I do this?
Only one coat of EpoxyShield is needed on most concrete floors. If a second coat is needed / desired, it can be applied once the initial coat has dried. For the best adhesion, **apply the second coat within 4 days of the first coat. If more than four days has passed, the surface will either need to be scuff sanded** or primed with our Garage and Concrete Floor Primer before another coat can be successfully applied.  – [rustoleum](https://www.rustoleum.com/pages/homeowner/faqs/epoxyshield-garage-floor-coating-faqs/?page=3)

Comment: A one month cure on the slab is the minimum wait time before you can coat it with epoxy. I'd wait to see if you have 'hot tire pick up' problems before you re-coat. It was too young to have to acid etch, but you needed to have filled all the cracks first, or ran the roller sideways to squeegee it into the cracks better. - At the professional level, it doesn't matter how old it is, they'll grind the floor down; only way to be sure. - At the DiY level, honestly that's a pretty good coat, if you don't develop HTPU problems, count your blessings.

Comment: @Mazura it is a Polyaspartic coating, not epoxy :), product: https://www.amazon.com/Rust-Oleum-293513-Polycuramine-Garage-Floor/dp/B06XJ17JVD/ref=sr_1_12?crid=2UK7DD0HXILFF&dchild=1&keywords=polyaspartic+floor+coating&qid=1608879902&sprefix=polyspartic%2Clawngarden%2C231&sr=8-12

Comment: Okay, this then ;) > If applying a second coat of Terroxy Polyaspartic, the re-coat window is 2-4 hours. If beyond the 4 hours, **you must abrade the first coat** using 60-80 grit paper/screen. If second coat is not applied until after 24 hours, use 36 grit paper. – [tmsupply](https://www.tmsupply.com/downloads/Terroxy%20Polyaspartic%20-%20PDS.pdf) PDF

Comment: "*Any solution will be appreciated.*" A solution to the cracks?

Comment: @AlaskaMan, yup :)

Comment: That's a new floor? I'm no expert, but that seems like an awful lot of cracking. The floor should've poured in sections and/or given relief cuts, to insure against widespread random cracking like that. The other feedback, that there were steps that should've been taken before the poly applied and of course the prep required now before another coat is applied, is accurate but ...

Comment: ... if you hired someone to do that floor, it seems like you might have cause for having them redo it without the cracks. Every concrete contractor I've talked to always says "it's not a question of when, but if", but excessive cracking still seems like a valid concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of coating like this should need extra work for preparing it.

The cracks :

- Mainly the cause of cracks comes from moisture (Water) and oil spilled on your floor. This moisture if you just spray the coating on it it will make your coating have microbubbles and leaving you with cracks.
- Or the concrete/floor is not porous as stated in the product application manual.

In the product application manual :

> SURFACE PREPARATION
> Proper surface preparation is critical to achieving the best results. Scrub heavily soiled areas with RockSolid Heavy Duty Degreaser or Rust-Oleum Cleaner & Degreaser (sold separately). Scrub thoroughly, then rinse. Repeat as needed. Use the supplied RockSolid concrete etch per the instructions to provide the proper surface condition to ensure proper adhesion. Rinse the floor thoroughly and allow it to dry completely.

You should let it clean first hand before you apply any coating.

[This user manual for your product from Amazon link you provide](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81xBGjInRPL.pdf)

If you didn't want to see a long PDF content, the summary of the solution:

- Scrap back all coating first. (paint or coating dust is dangerous, use proper equipment for your health)
- Clean your floor from oil.
- Let it completely dry.
- Check the porous or just sanding the floor would help the adhesion.
- Apply the coating (Refer to the PDF how to apply the coating, the instruction is too long in the summary answer)

I hope this will help you